# property 'list' does not exist on type 'Firebasedatabse' in ionic and property 'List' does not exist on type 'Firebasedatabse' in ionic

Tags: database, ionic-framework

In my IDE `list` and `object` are underlined. Can you tell me why?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject  } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

[image: list' does not exist on type 'Firebasedatabse]

Comment: Can you post just a smaller screenshot of the underline issue?

Comment: New screen shot is uploaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'list' does not exist on type 'database' and, Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<any>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171797/property-list-does-not-exist-on-type-database-and-property-push-does-not)